# Import a description-only line to MYOB

Tags: csv, myob

I'm writing a small application that generates a CSV file for import into MYOB. My client has requested the ability to import an invoice line that contains only the "Description" field for including in the invoice but which has no value.

When I try to import a line without amounts the import report skips that line and reports "Error -90:  Ex-GST Amount and Inc-GST Amount are invalid or blank."

Is there any way to import a non-value line into MYOB for printing in an invoice?

Comment: Are you setting the values to 0 or just leaving them blank? That error message sounds like they are blank. I'd have the qty = 1 and ex GST amount = 0 and Inc GST = 0

Comment: Thanks, I've been leaving them blank. I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the values to 0 or just leaving them blank? That error message sounds like they are blank. I'd have the qty = 1 and ex GST amount = 0 and Inc GST = 0

Comment: Just added this as an answer in case it worked for you and you want to mark it as accepted ;-)